# What does the city name Ankh-Morpork in Terry Pratchett's Discworld novels mean?

Tags: names, discworld

I would assume that someone has asked this question before but I haven't found any discussion about the name of Ankh-Morpork. Ever since I read my first Discworld book, I kept wondering about this name. I am not a native speaker, so I wonder if I miss any pun or reference to the real world?

Comment: Not an answer on the individual names, but on the double name construction: [Ankh-Morpork](https://wiki.lspace.org/mediawiki/Ankh-Morpork) is made up of [Ankh](https://wiki.lspace.org/mediawiki/Ankh_(city)) and [Morpork](https://wiki.lspace.org/mediawiki/Morpork). My speculation it is was inspired by a real life town like [Budapest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Budapest), made up of [Buda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buda) and [Pest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pest,_Hungary) (where both sides are also separated by a river).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

There's a discussion of this in [The Annotated Pratchett](https://www.lspace.org/books/apf/the-colour-of-magic.html).

> Terry has said that the name 'Ankh-Morpork' was inspired neither by the ankh (the Egyptian cross with the closed loop on top), nor by the Australian or New Zealand species of bird (frogmouths and small owls, respectively) that go by the name of 'Morepork'.

And apparently when somebody suggested that *Ankh-Morpork* was a takeoff on Fritz Leiber's city of *Lankhmar,* where most of the stories with Fafhrd and the Gray Mouser are set, Terry said

> "Bravd and the Weasel were indeed takeoffs of Leiber characters – there was a lot of that sort of thing in The Colour of Magic. But I didn't – at least consciously, I suppose I must say – create Ankh-Morpork as a takeoff of Lankhmar."

On the other hand, Bravd and the Weasel in *The Colour of Magic* are clearly takeoffs of Fafhrd and the Gray Mouser, and *Ankh-Mor* sounds very much like *Lankhmar*, so I think it's quite possible that Terry unconsciously used *Lankhmar* as a model for the name of the city.

Comment: Dang, beat me to it!

Comment: I've read your link, but I still wonder: Terry Pratchett said that he wasn't inspired by these words, but did he say why he _had_ chosen this name? Did he ever mention anything he had on his mind? Was it just the sound of the words? Was he just hungry at that time, thinking about having more pork with his next meal?

Comment: However, LATER it appears the Ankh-Morpork was retconned to be derived from the Ankh and the Morepork, as every representation of the city seal I've found shows a small owl holding an ankh in its claws. (Of course, it also shows hippopotami wearing gold chains, but what can you do? Fashion is so fickle...).

Comment: @Bob: Obviously that's in the other leg of the trousers of time...

Comment: @BobJarvis: Yeah, I'm surprised to learn that wasn't the original intent...

Comment: @BobJarvis: Or it could just be a pun in-universe. They're common in heraldry in our world: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canting_arms

Comment: The over-specific dementi is overly specific: While *the Ankh* may not be the idea, the word has many meanings and the derivation of the symbol is naturally mystic. Maybe Prattchett had a peculiar association not fit for sharing, for one reason or another. Personally, punning around a bit, I could see it as a pun on *Ang, Angl-*, whence *England, English*, often thought to mean "narrow", but that's equally mysterious. Indeed in-universe, Ankh is a river, and terms meaning *narrow* often describe narrow, shallow parts of a river where to settle. *-pork* may be *park*, *more* maybe *moor*.

Answer (score 5):

On a slightly more surreal note, Pratchett jokes in the Fifth Elephant that 'Morpork' is the word in the Beyonk language of Uberwald for an item of ladies' underwear.

Lord Vetinari quickly cuts off Vimes when he starts speculating about exactly which item.

Probably more of a tongue in cheek joke than intended seriously but potentially relevant to the discussion?

Comment: Anything the Patrician says is relevant to the discussion...and vice versa...

Answer (score 3):

Hmmm.... maybe the name came from this brand of meat product from ages ago?

[image: old commercial]

(note the `MOR PORK` tin in the first train car)

Comment: It certainly doesn't come from a description of Throat's sausages...